# Read configuration files from external directory in Play framework

Tags: playframework, sbt

I know there are countless questions about putting `application.conf` outside of the app, answered by using the `config.file` system property, but we have a different situation.

We have a Play app that uses a library which reads its own configuration file from the classpath as `/sys-config.xml`. It can't be configured to use a different path. The problem is we want this to be outside of the deployment, so we can't put it in `conf/` and we can't just set `config.file`. We need to add an arbitrary directory to the classpath for the Play app to pick up and find when looking for resources. I've tried setting `CLASSPATH` but it looks like it's either ignored, or not passed through by Activator/SBT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is simply an SBT thing, and you just need to add something to `externalDependencyClasspath` which you can grab from the system property of your choice.

```
externalDependencyClasspath in Runtime ++= sys.props.get("config.dir")
  .map(f => Seq(file(f)))
  .getOrElse(Nil)
```

We can now run `./activator -Dconfig.dir=/var/xyz run` and it will find `application.conf` and `sys-config.xml` in that directory.